# Odoo Onchange method doesn't update select field

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, odoo

I have two selectbox field in the form employee and department. I want to pick department automatically when I pick employee according to employee's department_id.

Here is my .py code (Odoo 11)

```
class HrExpenseExpense(models.Model):
_inherit = "hr.expense"

department_expense_group = fields.Selection(
    string='Department Expense Group',
    related='department_id.expense_group',
    readonly=True,
)
department_id = fields.Many2one('hr.department', string='Department',
                                states={'post': [('readonly', True)], 'done': [('readonly', True)]})

@api.onchange('employee_id')
def onchange_employee_id(self):
    department_id = [x.id for x in self.employee_id.department_id]
    return {'domain': {'department_id': [('id', 'in', department_id)]}}
```

And xml view file:

```
 <xpath expr="//field[@name='employee_id']" position="after">
   <field name="department_expense_group" invisible="1" />
   <field name="department_id" invisible="0"/>
 </xpath>
```

It's working but problem is this; when I pick an employee, department selectbox updating automatically, it's triggering but not selecting automatically. Selectbox's list filling after I click to it. It must be selected automatically according to employee choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only changing the filter of the field `department_id` and have to set it on self to fulfill your requirement. And you're looping on a single record field (`employee_id.department_id`) which is a bit overblown here.

```py
@api.onchange('employee_id')
def onchange_employee_id(self):
    if self.employee_id:
        department = self.employee_id.department_id
        # set department
        self.department_id = department
        # don't allow other departments
        return {'domain': {'department_id': [('id', '=', department.id)]}}
    else:
        # empty department
        self.department_id = False
        # allow other departments
        return {'domain': {'department_id': [('id', '!=', False)]}}
```